# Tkinter filedialog как получить файл выбранный пользователем для изменение его типа

Tags: python, tkinter, moviepy

мир! У меня на стадии разработке простой программы на python с помощью библиотек: Tkinter, time , moviepy, возникла проблема, короче суть в том, что я не могу понять, как файл выбранный пользователем программа может получить его и изменить тип с помощью moviepy, например с mp4 > mp3, просто мне интересно как создать это. Заранее ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО !!!

```
from tkinter import *
from moviepy.editor import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import time, threading

window = Tk()
window.geometry('600x600')
window.resizable(height=False,width=False)
window.title("easy convert")
window["bg"] = "gray"
     
def open_mp4():
    file_name = fd.askopenfilename(
        filetypes=(("MP3", "*.mp3"),
                  ))
    f = open(file_name)
    s = f.read()
    text.insert(1.0, s)
    f.close()

def progress():
    for i in range(101):
        pb['value'] += i
        time.sleep(.3)

 
def export_mp3():
    file_name = fd.asksaveasfilename(
        filetypes=(("MP3", "*.mp3"),
                  ))
    f = open(file_name, 'w')
    s = text.get(1.0, END)
    f.write(s)
    f.close()
        
save_radio = IntVar()
save_radio.set(0)
img = PhotoImage(file='ico.png')
#img = img.subsample(4,4)
img2 = PhotoImage(file='ico2.png')
#img2 = img2.subsample(4,4)
mp3_to_4 = Button(text='mp4 to mp3 convert',command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=progress, daemon=True).start() )
b1 = Button(text="Открыть",highlightthickness=0, bd= 0,bg='gray', command=open_mp4,image=img)
b1.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
mp3_to_4.grid(column=0,row=1)
b2 = Button(text="Сохранить",highlightthickness=0, bd= 0,bg='gray', command=export_mp3,image=img2) 
text = Text(width=50, height=25)
text.grid(columnspan=2)
b2.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
pb = ttk.Progressbar( mode="determinate")
pb.grid(row=0,column=0)
text_str = StringVar()
text_str.set ("Plz follow my TikTok Adammuesly")
label = Label( textvariable=text_str)
label.grid()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: суть моей идеи в том чтоб создать конвертер с помощью  moviepy, с графическим интерфейсом Tkinter , чтобы  конвертировать mp4 в mp3 простыми словами получать звук с видео

Comment: Не понятно зачем вам тип файла?

Comment: Сначала показываете пользователю диалог открытия файла, обрабатываете файл, потом показываете диалог сохранения, сохраняете с указанным именем и расширением.

Comment: Голосую за закрытие вопроса, т.к. судя по удаленному ответу, проблема автора была в том, что он файл не сохранил.